# cells w/in search window GRASS GIS

Tags: grass-gis, distance, search

I am trying to find all cells that are a certain distance and within a certain window from a cell of interest.

For example: I want all cells in a distance of 10m within a search window of 10 - 40 degrees (from North).

Any hint how to do that using either a GRASS function or shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could buffer the cell to 10m using `r.buffer`. Then use `r.cost` on the constant-value buffer with your starting cell as the starting point, which would make a cone. Run `r.slope.aspect` to get the aspect angle of the cone. Then use `r.mapcalc` to set certain angles to nodata or something. This will leave you with a map showing the area within a certain distance and angle window of your starting cell.

Here's some GRASS 6.4 code:

```bash
g.region w=0 e=40 s=0 n=40 res=0.5
echo "20,20,0" | r.in.xyz input=- output=cell_of_interest fs=','
r.buffer input=cell_of_interest output=coi_buffer distances=10
r.cost -k input=coi_buffer output=coi_cone start_rast=cell_of_interest 
r.slope.aspect elevation=coi_cone aspect=coi_cone_aspect
# note that angle is w.r.t. west not north
r.mapcalc target='if(coi_cone_aspect>10 && coi_cone_aspect<40,1,null())'
```

Here's what the results look like:

1. The result of `r.buffer`

[image]

2. The result of `r.cost`

[image]

3. The result of `r.aspect`

[image]

4. Final result after `r.mapcalc`. The angle isn't with respect to north though. So you'll need to convert the angle accordingly.

[image]

Comment: @wittich Thanks for the edit. I didn't know you could add a language tag like that, but now I do :)

Comment: Excellent. I'm glad I was able to help!